# div's inside wrapping div will not display

Tags: html, css

I am creating a responsive webpage. I have never had this problem before, but I can't seem to find a solution. I have created a wrapping div around 3 other div's but the 3 containing div's will not display for some reason, could somebody tell me why:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div class = "header">

        <div class = "logo">

        </div>

        <div class = "nav">

        </div>

        <div class = "search">

        </div>

    </div>

</body>


</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body { 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0; 
}

.header{

    height:20%;
    width:100%;

}

.logo{

    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:inline;
    background:blue;

}

.nav{

    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    display:inline;
    background:green;

}

.search{

    height:100%;
    width:30%;
    display:inline;
    background:orange;

}
```

Comment: because you've set them to be inline elements with no content?

Comment: you've used relative sizes for everything, but have no content, so the only height available to base your desired relative sizes is `0` - the height of an empty document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to change display to block and use `float`:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.header {
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
}
.logo {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:block;/*Change to block*/
    background:blue;
    float: left;
}
.nav {
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    display:block;/*Change to block*/
    background:green;
    float: left;
}
.search {
    height:100%;
    width:30%;
    display:block;/*Change to block*/
    background:orange;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="nav"></div>
    <div class="search"></div>
</div>
```

And another one is simple to use `display: inline-block`:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.header {
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
}
.logo {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;/*Change to inline-block*/
    background:blue;
}
.nav {
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    display: inline-block;/*Change to inline-block*/
    background:green;
}
.search {
    height:100%;
    width:30%;
    display: inline-block;/*Change to inline-block*/
    background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="nav"></div>
    <div class="search"></div>
</div>
```

Both will work.

Comment: how would I display these divs inline with each other?

Comment: Also you can just use `display: inline-block`. Please don't forget to accept it:)

Comment: Also +1 wouldn't heart :)

Comment: One solution is yo use `font-size: 0` to the container, in this case  `header` and apply `font-size: Xpx` to child elements like `.header > div{
    font-size: 16px;
}`. Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/oL0quekh/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the heights of the elements.
You can't have percentage as a height if you don't have a fixed number to refer to.

Example:

```
body { height: 500px; }
```